# Maven throwing errors during the clean command - Eclipse/Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I created a simple test project in Maven since I'm new to using it and trying to learn. I was preparing to set up a .jar file, but when I went to run a build and clean in the project, I keep getting these errors:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Aaron/Downloads/Eclipse%20Installer/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.16.0.20200610-1735/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/C:/Users/Aaron/Downloads/Eclipse%20Installer/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Aaron/Downloads/Eclipse%20Installer/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.16.0.20200610-1735/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/C:/Users/Aaron/Downloads/Eclipse%20Installer/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/5/0/.cp/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
```

[image]

What exactly would be causing this or how do I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These are not errors. SLF4J is an API, and it needs a compatible binding (implementation). Without a binding, it writes to STDERR, which shows up as a red line in Eclipse.

A possible cause in your case is that Maven is not being run from an external JRE, but from the justj JRE plugin which contains SLF4J.  Somewhere in the classpath, SLF4J finds two or more bindings and then settles on one binding, and then Maven proceeds smoothly.

If you don't like to see the red lines, try to run Maven from an external JRE or JDK.  That will not have SLF4J during the Maven launch classpath. This can be done from the 'run' configurations for Maven and another JRE or JDK can be specified.

Comment: So, how exactly do I run Maven from an external JRE or JDK? Are you saying that I've installed or set up Maven incorrectly? I've set the main Maven folder into my Java folder located here:  

C:\Program Files\Java\apache-maven-3.6.3

Where exactly was I supposed to install or set the Maven folder, if so.

Comment: Eclipse has built-in Maven and the version of Eclipse you appear to be using has an embedded Java as well.  Somewhere in that plugin classpath is the problem.  It would be hard to troubleshoot it.  Maybe you can use Eclipse without JRE and install JDK independently and include the JDK in eclipse.ini if it is not already on the path.  That would give you a starting point to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

These are just warnings, Not error. we get these in the console when multiple versions of the files are available. You can remove those files manually to remove these warnings. JDK automatically selects the best one suitable for use.

This usually occurs when we change the version of a dependency in pom.xml